# Kubuntu dependancies are required but not installable

Tags: kubuntu, dpkg

I am trying to install a software call OpentTeacher, but none of the methods I have tried have worked. When I try to use apt-get it says `unable to locate package`. When I download the .deb file and try to install using dpkg, I get:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openteacher:
 openteacher depends on python:any (<< 2.8).
 openteacher depends on python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~).
 openteacher depends on python-pyqt5; however:
  Package python-pyqt5 is not installed.
 openteacher depends on python-pyqt5.qtopengl; however:
  Package python-pyqt5.qtopengl is not installed.
 openteacher depends on python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia; however:
  Package python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia is not installed.
 openteacher depends on python-pyqt5.qtquick; however:
  Package python-pyqt5.qtquick is not installed.
 openteacher depends on python-pyqt5.qtwebkit; however:
  Package python-pyqt5.qtwebkit is not installed.
 openteacher depends on python-chardet; however:
  Package python-chardet is not installed.
 openteacher depends on python-enchant; however:
  Package python-enchant is not installed.
 openteacher depends on python-urwid; however:
  Package python-urwid is not installed.
```

And whenever I try use apt-get now it displays this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openteacher : Depends: python:any (< 2.8) but it is not installable
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~) but it is not installable
               Depends: python-pyqt5 but it is not installable
               Depends: python-pyqt5.qtopengl but it is not installable
               Depends: python-pyqt5.qtmultimedia but it is not installable
               Depends: python-pyqt5.qtquick but it is not installable
               Depends: python-pyqt5.qtwebkit but it is not installable
               Depends: python-chardet but it is not installable
               Depends: python-enchant but it is not installable
               Depends: python-urwid but it is not installable
```

If anyone knows how to fix this it would be very helpful.

Comment: You've not provided your systems release details, nor what release the downloaded .deb file you tried to install was packaged for (ie. was it built for the same release as you are running? as that is key detail to solving your package issues, but you've provided none of that detail; nor link to what you downloaded if you don't know)  FYI:  *The python version details you provided imply it was built for something very old! as python2 has been EOL now for years*

Comment: It seems that the software is just out of date and hasnt been updated, and will not work

Comment: We are very limited given we don't know your release, nor did you provide clear details on "OpentTeacher" you also refer to as "openteacher" in pastes (ie. a typo?)  To be most helpful you should provide your release (*deb* packages are built for a release), and clues on the package you are trying to install (*you spell it two ways, but a link is also useful where typo free*).

Comment: The deb file is packaged for Ubuntu 10.10 (so indeed very old). In any case you may have more luck with the source code. That is, if we are talking about this http://openteacher.org/en/download.html